# How to join three queries with Union or any other way?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables and three queries. I want to count the number of rows in one table, the number of different rows in the second table and then Order by the average of the three. I tried using UNION but it seems like I only get the first query working. I used the code given on the first answer and it actually works. What i wanna do is get all the users with their count,count2 and count3, and list them on the table

This code just gets the info for one person. I wan the three queries to get the info based on the number of users.

Here's my query (UPDATED):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM users) t1
JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 FROM posts WHERE  `type` = 'Q' ) t2
JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count3 FROM posts WHERE `type` = 'A' ) t3
JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM article_history) t4
ORDER BY (t4.count + t2.count2 + t3.count3) / 3 DESC
```

What I want to get is all the users with those info order from the highest average to lowest but what i get is 3 different users all with the same info.

The above code gives an output like this  which is not what i expect:

| # | Username | count | count2 | count3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jake | 9 | 33 | 2 |
| 2 | James | 9 | 33 | 2 |
| 3 | John | 9 | 33 | 2 |

Comment: `COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows, not the number of columns in one table. If you want to count the columns, you need to query one of the system catalog views. Also, always use parameters in your statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues.

Comment: Can you post the expected results as table to better explain your requirements?

Comment: Your UNION ALL returns 3 rows. But your ORDER BY tries to order by the sum of these 3 values, which is a constant. I.e. the ORDER BY makes no sense at all. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want count all the rows in each table and then order the table by the average of the counted rows. I did succeed on that with the updated code. The problem now is to get each user and count the rows for each user. You can see it above.

Comment: As mentioned under AB Web Dev's answer: `JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN` and requires an `ON` or `USING` clause in SQL. MySQL should raise an error here, but it silently converts this into `CROSS JOIN`. You don't want to cross join the same totals to all users, though. You want to inner join users' totals, so you need totals per user. See my answer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have completely changed the query in your request, it seems you want to select all users with their respective counts and use these counts to order the userid rows.

```
WITH
  questions AS
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS question_count
    FROM posts
    WHERE `type` = 'Q'
    GROUP BY userid
  ),
  answers AS
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS answer_count
    FROM posts
    WHERE `type` = 'A'
    GROUP BY userid
  ),
  history AS
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS history_count
    FROM article_history
    GROUP BY userid
  )
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN questions q USING (userid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers   a USING (userid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN history   h USING (userid)
ORDER BY COALESCE(q.question_count, 0) +
         COALESCE(a.answer_count, 0) + 
         COALESCE(h.history_count, 0) DESC;
```

The problem with your query is that you are not counting the answers, questions and history per user, but over all users instead. Then you cross join these totals to each user. You need `GROUP BY` to get counts per user and inner joins to joins users counts to their users.

I assume here that all tables have a userid that we can use for the join. If this column is called differently in the tables, then you'll have to adjust the query slightly, of course.

Comment: It gives an error saying unknown column userid in the from clause. The column userid exists in the posts table. Only the history table has a different name (user). I changed the userid with user but still im getting that error. Can it be because there are two queries geting userid from the same table?

Comment: You can either change the `USING` clauses to `ON` clauses or use an alias: `SELECT user AS userid, COUNT(*) AS history_count FROM article_history GROUP BY user`.

Comment: I consider the name `user` a design flaw, by the way. If that column contains the userid, why is it called user and not userid? Stay consistent with the naming in your database, so that it is always evident what the columns contain.

Comment: Yes, It contains user id but i give them different names because it wouldnt cause problem in joining tables, I will fix it though. And I changed The USING to ON which said that userid is ambigous so changed each of them to different names l like :  (SELECT userid AS ids...)  and the other to (SELECT userid AS userids...). It worked  with no errors but then the table was a mess. All the users were repaeated twice and the counted values werent correct as well. I really appreciate the help but it isnt working , I know i am really bad at this :(

Comment: The counts must be correct. Once you group by user, you'll get counts by user. As to the column names: `USING` is convenient, and all you'll have to do is use an alias to match the userid in the users table. If you work with `ON`, then explicitly `SELECT u.userid, q.question_count, ...` instead of `SELECT *` so as to get the userid just once.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very very very much! I changed the userids all to the same name and went with  USING. The counts are also correct now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are using `UNION` and the `UNION` works with same column or same alias name but you are using the different alias name for each like `count`, `count2`, `count3`

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM history WHERE user ='$userid' ) t1
    JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 FROM posts WHERE userid ='$userid' AND `type` = 'Q' ) t2
    JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count3 FROM posts WHERE userid ='$userid' AND `type` = 'A' ) t3
    ORDER BY (t1.count + t2.count2 + t3.count3) / 3 DESC
";
```

Updated working query as per your new requirement

```
SELECT * 
FROM users t1
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS QuestionCount 
       FROM posts WHERE  `type` = 'Q' GROUP BY userid ) t2 USING (userid)
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS AnswerCount 
       FROM posts WHERE `type` = 'A'  GROUP BY userid ) t3 USING (userid)
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS HistoryCount 
       FROM article_history  GROUP BY userid) t4  USING (userid);
```

This way, you can get the counts from each table and order the results based on the calculated average of the counts.

Comment: Your query returns one single row, no need to ORDER BY.

Comment: Yes i noticed that. I have updated the queries, and can you check if they are correct. Tnx

Comment: MySQL allows inner joins without an `ON` clause, but it shouldn't. This is invalid SQL. If you want to cross join the three rows, then use `CROSS JOIN`, not `[INNER] JOIN`.

Comment: yes you are right as per requirement this query will work
`SELECT * 
FROM users t1
INNER JOIN ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS QuestionCount FROM posts WHERE  type = 'Q' GROUP BY userid ) t2 USING (userid)
INNER JOIN ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS AnswerCount FROM posts WHERE type = 'A'  GROUP BY userid ) t3 USING (userid)
INNER JOIN ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS HistoryCount FROM article_history  GROUP BY userid) t4  USING (userid);`